# Reordering rows within a grid Ext JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to reorder the rows within a single grid. Im relatively new to extjs and have tried searching for this but all the resources i find are for older ext js versions and some of properties defined in those aren't valid anymore. eg- http://www.vinylfox.com/getting-started-with-grid-drag-drop/

```
    xtype: 'grid',
    id: 'row-grid',
    hideHeaders: true,
    store: 'SelectedRowStore',
    //enableDragDrop: true,
    //ddGroup: 'rowgrid-dd',
    columns: [
        {
            header: 'Rows',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: false,
            dataIndex: 'DisplayName'
        }, 
        {
            id: 'button-column',
            dataIndex: 'ID',
            sortable: true,
            hideable: false,
            width: 35,
            renderer: PA.common.RendererHelper.renderButtonForAddRowMainGrid
        }
    ]
```

I'd really appreciate any help/advice on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [grid to grid drag-n-drop example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html). It works with two grids, but I'm sure it can be easily modified to allow rearranging rows within one grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the sencha sample as Rene said or follow this:

Add this to your grid:

```
       viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                containerScroll: true,
                dragGroup: 'someuniquenameforyourgrid',
                dropGroup: 'someuniquenameforyourgrid'
            },
        },
```

And, only if you need some listener to do some anction, add (inside viewConfig):

```
       listeners: {
            drop: 'onDropGrid'
        }
```

and event handler code in your controller:

```
   onDropGrid: function (node, data, dropRec, dropPosition) {
       ...
   }
```